# Are there monsters with a natural ability to move between planes without casting a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, planes

I am preparing to DM a campaign in a world of my own design, and I require a monster to fill an important plot function.

The campaign is set in a pocket plane that is almost entirely cut off from the wider multiverse. As part of the plot, the characters are sent to hunt a monster that has managed to travel onto the plane due to its innate inter-planar abilities.

The PCs will be level 5 or 6 by this point.

I was originally looking at Phase Spiders, but having looked them up, their abilities are more about phasing between the material and ethereal planes, not so much travelling from one plane to another.

Are there any monsters in the 5e MM of up to roughly CR 6 (need not be exact), or from earlier editions that might be converted, that have natural inter-planar abilities?

It has to be a natural ability rather than a spell, since the idea is that the corpses of the creatures can be harvested for a material to be used in a planeshifting ritual for plot purposes.

Comment: @daze413 Probably something around CR 3? I'm still not very good at using CR. Sorry.

Comment: Would you accept creatures that can simply cast *plane shift* innately?

Comment: Ok, I did some reading on CR and have a better idea now. The party will be level 5 or level 6 at this point (encounter CR of 6 will be good), and I am happy for it to be a group of creatures. The only stipulation is that it is a natural ability to cross planes rather than a spell. The idea being that the corpses of the creatures can be harvested for a material to be used in a planeshifting ritual.

Comment: What is this "paneshift ritual" you speak of and why does it rule out the use of spells? What counts as a "natural ability"?

Comment: @Szega The ritual is a plot thing. Ordinary planar travel spells don't work on the plane. As for "Natural", I mean like abilities that the monster is born with. Like, Phase Spiders are just naturally able to phase. That's part of their magical physiology I guess.

Comment: Then *innate* spellcasting should also be ok, shouldn't it?

Comment: @szega No, I don't think so. I'm not looking for a creature that knows how to cast a planeshift spell. Rather, a creature that by its very nature crosses planes. There may not be one, which is why I ask. The idea is that normal planar magic doesn't work there, but the strange inter-planar abilities of the monsters have allowed them to come in, and their blood/ichor has that magic in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### There are none which match your requirements, but you can customize an existing creature to give it this ability

There are no creatures in the D&D 5e Monster Manual which can shift between planes other than Ethereal without the use of an ability considered as innate spellcasting.

Some creatures around CR6 can use innate spellcasting or psionics to planeshift. These include the cambion (CR5, p.36), githyanki knight (CR8, p.160), githzerai zerth (CR6, p.161), night hag (CR5, p.178), and mind flayer (CR7, p.222).

As a DM, you can always simply invent your own monsters or modify an existing one so that it can plane shift. The easiest solution is to simply take an existing creature and make a variant that can shift between planes. This gives you an official and well-balanced monster which fills the niche required.

Making a variant monster in this way is an officially endorsed rule in the Dungeon Master's Guide, p. 273:

> Part of the D&D experience is the simple joy of creating new monsters and customizing texisting ones, if for no other reason than to surprise and delight your players with something they've never faced before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a suspicion this would be the case. Looks like modified Phase Spiders it will be!